# Add a smooth line of the average concentration

Tags: r, ggplot2, smoothing

I am trying to add a geom_smooth line of the average of Size to the code.

```
ggplot(data = Birds, 
       aes(Species, size, color=Subject)) +
  geom_line() +
  labs (x = "Species",
        y = "Size(cm)",
        title = "Size and Species of Birds") +
  theme_bw()
```

Comment: Can you provide some more information on what you're after? Is there an example you can share?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for? Adding `color=Subject` to the `aes` will create a different line for each subject. Because each subject has received different doses, but they are measured at the same time intervals, plottling geom_line() creates some funky results if you don't split the lines based on subject. In other words, you have multiple y values for a single x value.

```
ggplot(data = Theoph, 
       aes(Time, conc)) +
  geom_smooth()+
  #geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  labs (x = "Time after dose (hours)",
        y = "Theophylline oncentration (mg/L)",
        title = "Theophylline concentration in all subjects over time") +
  coord_equal() +
  theme_bw()
```

If you wanted just a single clean line for the average, you could do that outside of the `ggplot` "pipe", then plot the new average. There is probably a way to do it all in `ggplot` though, I just don't know.

Comment: Also if you want to keep the color for the points you can do `geom_point(aes(color = Subject)`.